# How to disable Sitecore Custom Submit Action OK button until mappings are chosen

Tags: javascript, sitecore9, sitecore-speak-ui

Sitecore (9.3) I have created several custom Submit Actions and I noticed on one of the default ones, "Trigger Outcome", the ok button is disabled until the mappings are chosen.

[image: Unchosen mappings]

As soon as you choose the mappings, the 'ok' button is enabled.

[image: chosen mappings]

I tried setting the IsRequired checkbox on the item in SCRocks, but it only seems to make an asterisk* and not make it required/ok button disabled

[image: property isRequired]
[image: form element]

I tracked down the toggle code to a file sourced from ~/speak/v1/components/ToggleButton.js, I think... but I am not really sure, it gets convoluted.

The JS files referenced for each of these default SA's have beefier code than the code used in the Sitecore Doc:

[Walkthrough: Creating a custom submit action that updates contact details](https://doc.sitecore.com/en/developers/93/sitecore-experience-manager/walkthrough--creating-a-custom-submit-action-that-updates-contact-details.html)

Anyone go through this before? How to I accomplish this?

Thanks much.

Answer (score 2):

This functionality could be achievable through below code in the speak JS file.

Check this out through bowser console window.
[screen shot attached for the same](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vfOpw.png)
For enabling button
`parentApp.setSelectability(parentApp.pageCode,true)`

For disabling button
`parentApp.setSelectability(parentApp.pageCode,false)`

From TriggerOutcome.js check below line of JS code

```
initialized: function () {

                this.ItemTreeView.on("change:SelectedItem", this.changedSelectedItemId, this);
                this.CurrencyDropList.on("change:SelectedValue", this.changedSelectedItemId, this);

            },

changedSelectedItemId: function () {
                var isSelectable = this.ItemTreeView.SelectedItem.$templateId === outcomeTemplateId && this.CurrencyDropList.SelectedValue;
                parentApp.setSelectability(this, isSelectable, this.ItemTreeView.SelectedItemId);
            },
```

Hope you get clear idea. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can achieve this functionality by setting up some parameters for field names and conditions for ParentApp in your custom submit action js file.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).